# Shopify Private App Configuration returning oauth error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, shopify-app

My app is in Ruby on Rails and I am trying to install it on to Shopify.
I created a private app on Shopify through the partners dashboard. When I enter the domain (example.shopify.com) I created in Shopify in the login page, 
I get this error:
Oauth error invalid_request: The Shopify API application does not support oauth

The url i'm redirected to is this: 
https://example.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=c54817f9011be80129703e1987a4a37e&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fshopify%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=read_products&state=2c0c64c657dd9a212e088f7018c6e8fe4ba87c39e4542ec1

My code for configuration is this:

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
  config.application_name = "APP NAME"
  config.api_key = env['SHOPIFY_API_KEY']
  config.secret = env['SHOPIFY_API_SECRET']
  config.old_secret = ""
  config.scope = env['SHOPIFY_PERMISSIONS']
  config.embedded_app = true
  config.after_authenticate_job = false
  config.api_version = "2020-01"
  config.shop_session_repository = 'Shop'
  config.webhooks = [
    {topic: 'orders/create', address: "#{ENV['APP_HOST']}/webhooks/orders/order_create", format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'fulfillments/create', address: "#{ENV['APP_HOST']}/webhooks/orders/order_fulfilled", format: 'json'}
  ]
end
```

Am i using the wrong url format?
I'm not sure what to set 'APP_HOST' to be in env file either.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same problem, I realized I was adding the app as a private app in my store rather than as a public app in the partners dashboard. After that realization I followed the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGxeoAHlQOg